# Add an interval to a date until is today sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, intervals, dateadd

I need to query a table to get all rows where a date field + any amount of 7 day intervals is today, the date will only be in the past and can be any number of days in the past.

For example if today is 2014-06-27 and we have the table below:

```
Table A
------------------
ID    | Date
------------------
1     | 2014-06-13
------------------
2     | 2014-06-14
------------------
3     | 2014-05-30
------------------
```

The rows `1` and `3` should be returned, but row `2` shouldn't because `2014-06-14 + 2 x 7 day intervals = 2014-06-28` which is after today.

Comment: So, essentially you're just looking for dates that fall on the same day-of-week as `Today`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
  Select * 
    from A
    where datediff(dd,date,getdate())% 7 = 0
```